# Logstash Grok Filter for Opentracing in Quarkus' log

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, quarkus

Working on getting our Quarkus log files into elasticsearch. My problem is in trying to process the logs in logstash... How can I get the traceId and spanId using grok filter?

Here's a sample log entry:

```
21:11:32 INFO  traceId=50a4f8740c30b9ca, spanId=50a4f8740c30b9ca, sampled=true [or.se.po.re.EmployeeResource] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) getEmployee with [id:2]
```

Here is my grok:

```
%{TIME} %{LOGLEVEL} %{WORD:traceId} %{WORD:spanId} %{GREEDYDATA:msg}
```

Using grok debugger, it seem traceId and spanId are not detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFIK Grok expressions need to be exactly as the original text. So try to add commas, spaces and event all the text you do not want to capture. For instance `traceId=`

```
%{TIME} %{LOGLEVEL}  traceId=%{WORD:traceId}, spanId=%{WORD:spanId}, %{GREEDYDATA:msg}
```

This is the output from https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ for your log line and my grok expression suggestion.

```
{
  "TIME": [
    [
      "21:11:32"
    ]
  ],
  "HOUR": [
    [
      "21"
    ]
  ],
  "MINUTE": [
    [
      "11"
    ]
  ],
  "SECOND": [
    [
      "32"
    ]
  ],
  "LOGLEVEL": [
    [
      "INFO"
    ]
  ],
  "traceId": [
    [
      "50a4f8740c30b9ca"
    ]
  ],
  "spanId": [
    [
      "50a4f8740c30b9ca"
    ]
  ],
  "msg": [
    [
      "sampled=true [or.se.po.re.EmployeeResource] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) getEmployee with [id:2]"
    ]
  ]
}
```

As other users have mentioned, it is important to notice the spaces between the words. For instance, there are two spaces between the logLevel and the traceId. You can use the `s+` regular expression to forget about them. But maybe using it too much has a big (and bad) impact on performance.

```
%{TIME}\s+%{LOGLEVEL}\s+traceId=%{WORD:traceId},\s+spanId=%{WORD:spanId},\s+%{GREEDYDATA:msg}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be a couple of things:

- The spacing between fields might be off (try adding `\s?` or perhaps `\t` after `%{LOGLEVEL}`)
- The `%{WORD}` pattern might not be picking up the value because of the inclusion of `=`

Something like this pattern could work (you might need to modify it some):

```
^%{TIME:time} %{LOGLEVEL:level}\s?(?:%{WORD:traceid}=%{WORD:traceid}), (?:%{WORD:spanid}=%{WORD:spanid}), (?:%{WORD:sampled}=%{WORD:sampled}) %{GREEDYDATA:msg}$
```